# midiutil with python doesnt write drumset sounds in channel 10?

Tags: python, midi

Im trying to write a complete music using midiutil library with python. So far, i have been able to add any instrument i've wanted via

> MIDIFile.addProgramChange(track, channel, time, program)

and taking the program number from the table at https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/gm-level-1-sound-set

However, i cant add any drumset sounds the way i want. I know channel 10 is reserved for percussion, but whenever i write anything via

> MyMIDI.addNote(track, 10, pitch, time + i, duration, volume)

the sound played by musescore is played in the piano voice or in the voice defined by the ProgramChange method. I know there is drumset sounds somewhere in my computer because i have been able to manually add drumset sounds in musescore. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humans begin counting at one, so you have channels 1 … 16.
Computers begin couting at zero, so they have channels 0 … 15.

The [addNote() documentation](https://midiutil.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.1/class.html#midiutil.MidiFile.MIDIFile.addNote) says that the `channel` parameter is an integer from 0 to 15, so you must use `9` for the percussion channel.

Comment: Thanks so much! I used addNote with channel 9 and it worked perfectly.